# How to detect if an `img` element load has started and/or a request has been made to the server

Tags: html, image

Is there an easy/efficient way to detect if an `img` element load has started and/or a request has been made to the server?

I swear I remember seeing (the first part of) this before on SO, but can't find it now.

I think I remember that the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties are present if the image has started loading, but IDK if that is always true.

I am working with lazy loading, and would like to be able to prevent a request if one has not already been made. I more or less need to know as much as possible on this topic.

Specifically, in this particular case, the only place I can put JS is after the body, and we're not sure yet if converting every image to use `data-src` instead of `src` from the server is an option, so that may mean having to comb back through the DOM to figure out where everything is at, and try to cancel as much as possible without stopping anything that is already in progress, because that would cause redundancy (even though it may help metrics in a very dirty way).

BTW, we are not using browser-native lazy loading, because I've found that is only useful for a specific use case. It's can't *really* be relied upon for prioritizing images above the fold, since it loads some lazy elements below the fold *before* the window.load event fires. Which makes no sense to me (why it can't start doing that *after* window.load.) And why there are no options on the feature. Also why `loading:lazy` can't be set in CSS.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Browsers are smart enough to optimize and cache requests on their own. Besides, you can control request caching with meta headers and server config.

Comment: @EriksKlotins, Ultimately trying to defer loading of all images below the fold until after window.load fires. I didn't think that was a caching issue.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful then: https://nitropack.io/blog/post/defer-offscreen-images

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to control image loading:

https://jsfiddle.net/xnp6hLr4/2/

Your best bet is to load images dynamically and keep track of their states (not loaded, loading, loaded)

```
var isLoaded = false;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#image').one().bind('load',(function(){alert('loading complete'); isLoaded=true;  }));

    $('#startButt').click(function(){

        if (isLoaded)
        {
            alert('Image already loaded');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Loading start');
            $('#image').attr('src', 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/08/31/11/01/kangaroo-7423042_960_720.jpg');
        }   
     });
});
```